# Does anybody know what this shark is eating?

Tags: ichthyology, species-identification

Looking for a species identification on the orange fish that the shark is eating. The shark is a goblin shark filmed as part of the BBC's 'Legends of the Deep: Deep Sea Sharks'.

[image]

Comment: It might be Helicolenus dactylopterus, but it is difficult to say for sure without being able to see the dorsal fin.

Comment: That's great, thank you. Just had a quick Google image search and I think you're right. Answer the question rather than a comment and I shall accept it!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fish in this image is *Helicolenus dactylopterus*. Shown below;

[image: Helicolenus dactylopterus]

This fish, is more formally known as a [**Blackbelly Rose-Fish**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackbelly_rosefish). This fish, is one of the Goblin Sharks' many prey in the deep sea.

In the photo you posted it looks as if the Goblin shark effortlessly and oddly so caught the fish - it did. This is due to how it consumes most of its prey:

> When they approach it their jaw goes out similar to how a human can stick out its tongue. Then with a sucking motion they draw they prey into their mouth where very powerful teeth are waiting to consume it.

Goblin sharks are quite terrifying...